What is the degeneracy of the free electron bands in a FCC lattice?
In Ashcroft and Mermin, the band structure diagram for free electrons in a FCC bravais lattice is provided. This diagram is shown at the end of this post.
For starters, each band shown has a trivial degeneracy : each state in each band can accommodate both a spin up and down electron. In addition to this degeneracy, the text states that "the number of dots on a curve (in the diagram below) specifies the number of degenerate free electron levels represented by the curve".  So now if we look at the lowest band in the diagram in the direction going from $\Gamma$ to X (shown by the green arrow), we see only one dot. Thus, we can assume that this band is two fold degenerate (ignoring the spin degeneracy). But I can't understand why this degeneracy is so low. If we go from $\Gamma$ to $-X$ we should get the same energy band (this is one degeneracy). But now if we go from $\Gamma$ to the boundary of the 1st Brillouin zone in the direction $k_z$ we should get another degeneracy. Similarly, from $\Gamma$ to the boundary of the 1st Brillouin zone in the directions $k_y$ and $-k_y$ give us two more degeneracies. My understanding is that the lowest band in the $\Gamma$ to $X$ direction should have a six fold degeneracy (in addition to the two fold spin degeneracy). This six-fold degeneracy comes from all six directions starting from $\Gamma$ and then going to the center of the 6 diamond faces on the first Brillouin zone shown in the diagram ( 5 of these center points are labelled with a pink circle and the other is the X point).
So does the band labelled by the green arrow below have a two-fold degeneracy as claimed by the text or a six-fold degeneracy as argued by me? Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!


You just misunderstand. The counting is once per $k$ value. $-X$ counts separately as $X$ even though it is obviously degenerate.

In the diagram the branch (shown by the green arrow) goes from $\Gamma$ to $X$. It does not go to any other of the 6 diamond faces that you mention, so it does for that reason not indicate the extra solutions that those branches would give.

@naturallyInconsistent Thanks for the comment. Okay so then the band from $\Gamma$ to X is one-fold degenerate (because the other five equivalent paths are not counted) right?  If this is the case, then why does the lowest band from L to W have 2 dots (indicating 2  fold degeneracy)? Infact, where does the extra degeneracy come from for all the bands with many dots if only one path is counted?

@JosBergervoet thanks for the comment. Okay so if each path is counted only once, then why do any of these bands show degeneracy at all? For example, the lowest band for the path from X to W has two dots indicating 2 fold degeneracy (at the very least it indicates that it has greater degeneracy than the path indicated by the arrow as that only has one dot). Where does this extra degeneracy come from?
